# Do you natives say "will you mind doing something"?

Tags: word-choice, subjunctives, politeness

I know that it is polite to say "**would you mind buying me a newspaper?**".

But can we say "**will you mind buying me a newspaper?**" though I feel it is uncommon.

Comment: My wife and I are native English speakers and we often ask each other "Would you mind doing .... for me?" or "Would you mind if we .... ?"

Comment: Why is it impolite? As a native speaker, it just sounds like a future request... "Tomorrow, will you buy me a paper?"

Comment: "would you mind buying me a newspaper?" is a polite request. "will you mind buying me a newspaper?" is a prediction as to whether it will bother you or not.

Answer (score 1):

We might say

> Will you mind buying me (something)?

but we would much more likely use *would you.*

It would not necessarily be seen as impolite, though it tends to suggest that the speaker assumes that the listener is going to buy them something.

The use of *would* communicates remoteness and is generally considered polite because it theoretically makes it easier for the listener to respond with something like *Sorry, I can't (because ...).*

It's possible that some people would sometimes use *will* instead of *would* unconsciously or unthinkingly, and there's a good chance a listener may not notice the difference. But I think it would be relatively unusual.

We would more likely use *Will you mind (something)* when, for example, I know that you will be doing something in the future. If I know that you are planning to go shopping on a busy shopping day, I might ask *Will you mind the crowds?*

If I know you are going to visit Antarctica, I might ask you *Will you mind the cold?*

So this is not a request for someone to do something. It is a question about whether they will be bothered when some expected future event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It has been portrayed in movies that a good looking woman may ask a man at the bar

> **Will** you buy me a drink?

which is different than the stereotyped

> Man: Can I buy you a drink?
>   Woman: I don't know, can you?

but usually "would you" gets used since it is a hypothetical proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind getting me a newspaper?

Will you mind getting me a newspaper?

Both the phrases "would you mind" and "will you mind"  are grammatically correct.

The use of the phrase "woud you mind"  is more usual as it's more polite.